# How to pass multiple parameters from thymeleaf html to thymeleaf dialect processor

Tags: java, html, jsp, thymeleaf

I am creating a custom thymeleaf dilect. I need to know how to pass parameters from thymleaf html fragment to dielect processor. I am able to achieve for one parameter but I need to know how we will achieve that for multiple parameters.
Below is my thymeleaf fragment.

> ```
> <th:block dialectPrefix:customDialect="${parameter}"> </th:block>
> ```

Below is my processor logic

> ```
> protected void doProcess(final ITemplateContext context, final IProcessableElementTag tag,
> final AttributeName attributeName, final String attributeValue,
> final IElementTagStructureHandler structureHandler) {
>   final IEngineConfiguration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
>   final IStandardExpression categoryExpression = parser.parseExpression(context, someString);
>   final IStandardExpressionParser parser = StandardExpressions.getExpressionParser(configuration);
>   String fetchValue=categoryExpression.execute(context).toString()
>    //I am able to get the value of parameter
> }
> ```

If I want to pass multi parameters from thymeleaf html like below

```
<th:block dialectPrefix:customDialect="${parameter1}" "${parameter2} etc">  </th:block>
```

I can separate it by `','` like `"${parameter1,parameter2}"` in html it works fine but I need to  split in my processor[.java] level .If any other way we can achieve that in html level that would help me.

Any one who has come across this can shed some light.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is natively supported.  You can see in the [code for `th:with`](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/6f65601cfcab7e108ca72293af76365bd5df7cf4/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/standard/processor/StandardWithTagProcessor.java) (which supports multiple assignments) that it's just processing the expression and splitting the input itself.

Comment: hi Metroids thanks for your inputs .Can you paste me the thymleaf html piece of code to be passed to parse AssignationUtils sequence  in doProcess method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done this way:

Call:

```
<th:block th:include="mailFragments::test('f1', 'f2', 'f3')"/>
```

Fragment:

```
 <th:block th:fragment="test(p1,p2,p3)">
    <element dialectPrefix:customDialect="|${p1},${p2},${p3}|">тест</element>
 </th:block>
```

And:

```
 new AbstractAttributeTagProcessor(TemplateMode.HTML, PREFIX, null, false, NAME, true, 1000, true) {
    @Override
    protected void doProcess(final ITemplateContext context, final ProcessableElementTag tag, final AttributeName name, String href, final IElementTagStructureHandler structureHandler) {
            final IEngineConfiguration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
            final IStandardExpressionParser parser = StandardExpressions.getExpressionParser(configuration);
            final IStandardExpression categoryExpression = parser.parseExpression(context, value);
            String delimitedResult = categoryExpression.execute(context).toString();
            String[] params = delimitedResult.split(",");
            .....
    }
```

PS: for custom thymeleaf tags see [Say Hello! Extending Thymeleaf in 5 minutes](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/sayhelloextendingthymeleaf5minutes.html)